# Basic Interface MTU Setting

Tags: mtu, interface

I would like some clarification on the MTU setting on an interface and the size attribute for ICMP.

I have two routers connected directly with an MTU of 1500 set on both sides. There is no dot1q, pppoe or other protocol running across the link, this is a bare bones setup.

I would have thought this should work.

```
ping x.x.x.x size 1500 donotfrag
```

Although it fails. It appears it only works at 1487.

If I increase the MTU to, for example 1514, I can then ping with df at 1500, but 1501 fails.

I was trying to connect this to a particular header size, for example an IP header, however minimum this would be 20 bytes, so I guess I am a bit confused as to why is it 14 bytes off.

I assume I am missing something straight forward :)

Comment: What brand are these routers? One of the tests we use when testing WAN circuits is to use a large number (10,000) of oversize (20,000) pings so that the packets must be fragmented and reassembled.

Comment: I'm guessing IOS-XR?

Comment: Runnning UNL with XRv